# Programmatically create Latest/Featured taxons and place them in the index page?

Tags: spree

I would like to how to create the latest and featured taxons without using the admin panel and place them into the index page (just like the spree_fancy website). I have tried to figure it out by studying the spree_fancy files but I need some help.

I fiddled with the spree_fancy to change the layout and I might have deleted something I shouldn't have. Even when I set a product with 'latest' taxon, I don't see the product under the 'latest' section in the index page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Creating `taxons` is easy:

```
2.0.0p247 :001 > Spree::Taxon.create(name: 'Featured') #you can add here any other attribute you want
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(...) 
 => #<Spree::Taxon id: 3, parent_id: nil, position: 0, name: "Featured", permalink: "featured", taxonomy_id: nil, lft: 5, rgt: 6, icon_file_name: nil, icon_content_type: nil, icon_file_size: nil, icon_updated_at: nil, description: nil, created_at: "2014-01-09 06:26:51", updated_at: "2014-01-09 06:26:51", meta_title: nil, meta_description: nil, meta_keywords: nil, depth: 0>
```

and that is all you need to create proper `Featured` taxon. You can check it in the [source](https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/master/app/controllers/spree/home_controller_decorator.rb), those taxons are distincted by their names. Do not forget about adding products to that taxon later.

As about second question, there are few possibilities:

1. I have linked above source of proper action, maybe you deleted taxons with that names? Or maybe you have overwrote those `@slider_products`, `@featured_products` and `@latest_products`?
2. Maybe your variables are fine, but you have changed views? You need something like [this](https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/blob/master/app/views/spree/home/index.html.erb#L15) to get them displayed. Check your Overrides and views replacements. If you were fiddling with CSS check that too, maybe HTML is fine, but you have done something with CSS (or even some JS).